# Login using Google+ on Parse

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I know this question has already been asked, but I couldn't find any solution. I am using Parse, where are users are able to login using Facebook, Twitter, and Google+. As of now, only Facebook and Twitter is fully functional.

I have managed to login using Facebook and Twitter in the following way:

```
private void onLoginButtonClicked() {
        LoginActivity.this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                LoginActivity.this, "", "Logging in...", true);
        List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_about_me",
                "user_relationships", "user_birthday", "user_location");
        ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(permissions, this, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                LoginActivity.this.progressDialog.dismiss();
                if (user == null) {
                    Log.d(IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication.TAG,
                            "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                } else if (user.isNew()) {
                    Log.d(IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication.TAG,
                            "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                    showUserDetailsActivity();

                } else {
                    Log.d(IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication.TAG,
                            "User logged in through Facebook!");
                moodpage();             

                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void onTwitterButtonClicked() {
        ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(this, new LogInCallback() {
              @Override
              public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                if (user == null) {
                  Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
                } else if (user.isNew()) {
                  Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Twitter!");
                  showUserDetailsActivity();        
                  } else {
                  Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Twitter!");
                  moodpage();               }
              }

            });
    }
```

I am trying to figure out to achieve this with Google+ through parse. Someone has suggested for me to look into Parse Rest API, however, I am not familiar with it, and need more guidance.

Some people have suggested me to use https://github.com/Glamdring/google-plus-java-api/ and looks promissing, but I am not sure how I would work that out.

for example lets say I have

```
    googleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twitterButton);
        googleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                onGoogleButtonClicked();
            }
        });

private void onGoogleButtonClicked(); {
        //what to input here
    }
```

Any clarification will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Parse.com only support facebook and twitter yet but not google+, for that you have to implement your own using authentication at cloud (parse.com) side

**This is long process so be patient**

**Follow this steps**

1) get google profile information for that **implement this necessary functions**

put in onCreate()

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this) //lets impement ConnectionCallbacks
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API) // lets implement OnConnectionFailedListener
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

**2) method of implemented OnConnectionFailedListener**

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), getActivity(),
                0).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
            // resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Method to resolve any signin errors for google plus
 * */
private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

3) **call on google+ button click**

```
private void loginUsingGoolgePlus() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mSignInClicked = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }

}
```

**4) methods of implemented ConnectionCallbacks**

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Get user's information
    getProfileInformation();

}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}
```

**5) this method will give you profile information**

```
/**
 * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
 * */
private void getProfileInformation() {
    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            final String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

            // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
            // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
            // replacing sz=X
            personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                    personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                    + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    googleAuthWithParse(email);
                }
            }).start();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**6) this is important** 
here we generate one token and using this and email id, we call script function  `accessGoogleUser` at cloud side (Parse.com) (this cloud code nothing but javascript `main.js`

-`accessGoogleUser` will give you accessToken using this accessToken you can do login or signup

```
protected void googleAuthWithParse(String email) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String scopes = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " ";
     String googleAuthCode = null;
    try {
        googleAuthCode = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                 getActivity(),                                           // Context context
                 email,                                             // String email
                 scopes,                                            // String scope
                 null                                      // Bundle bundle
         );
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GoogleAuthException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

     //Log.i(TAG, "Authentication Code: " + googleAuthCode);

    final HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("code", googleAuthCode);
    params.put("email", email);
    //loads the Cloud function to create a Google user
    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("accessGoogleUser", params, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void done(Object returnObj, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.e("AccessToken", returnObj.toString());
                ParseUser.becomeInBackground(returnObj.toString(), new LogInCallback() {
                    public void done(final ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                        if (user != null && e == null) {
                            showToast("The Google user validated");

                            if(user.isNew()){
                                  //isNew means firsttime   
                            }else{

                              loginSuccess();
                            }
                        } else if (e != null) {
                            showToast("There was a problem creating your account.");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                        } else
                            showToast("The Google token could not be validated");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                        if (e != null) {

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(e.getMessage());
                                showToast(jsonObject.getString("message"));
                            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                        }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**7) How to upload cloud code** `main.js` **at parse.com cloud**

read carefully and download Parse.exe and  from [here](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#command-line-installation) after download do

`place parse.exe and ParseConsole.exe in ':\Windows\System32' folder. Then search for Windows PowerShell in the start menu and run it as an administrator. Wait for the prompt in the window (mine was a blue window) to indicate it is in the ':\Windows\System32' folder. Then type '.\ParseConsole.exe' and press enter.`

**this how we upload files**

below files will create at C:\Users\xxxx while follow `image steps`

```
1) cloud
   - main.js
2) config
  ─ global.json
3) public
  ─ index.html
```

[image]

**8) download main.js** from [here](https://github.com/kishorejethava/goolge-with-parse.com/tree/master) and replace with default `main.js` which created in `cloud folder`

**Note :** don't forgot to add your client id and secret into this `main.js`

**9) check this too.!!**

`Require Revocable Sessions should be false` in parse data browser -> settings 
->General

**Ask me for any doubt. i am ready for help.!!**

Comment: Nice job! Works perfectly. My only problem is when I try to use the CloudCode via Rest Api. The user is created and I receive the session token in the fist attempt. But once the user is already created, I don't get the session token, only a blank response. Any idea why?

Comment: Missed that. Works like perfectly now. Tks a lot kishore

Comment: Glad to helped. Enjoy coding.!!

Comment: @kishorejethava getting sessionToken null after Parse server migration. please update your answer.